# Lua error when trying to extract OSRM data

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine, osmium

I am using a newer MacBook Pro with a Silicon chip. Following the example here (https://github.com/stanfordfuturebay/osrm-local), I am trying to extract data downloaded from https://download.geofabrik.de/ for use with osrm. After downloading, I run:

```
osrm-extract norcal-latest.osm.pbf
```

Here is the output:

```
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.185063] [info] Parsed 0 location-dependent features with 0 GeoJSON polygons
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.185586] [info] Using script profiles/car.lua
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.185607] [info] Input file: norcal-latest.osm.pbf
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.185615] [info] Profile: car.lua
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.185620] [info] Threads: 10
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.185938] [info] Parsing in progress..
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.186350] [info] input file generated by osmium/1.14.0
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.186819] [info] timestamp: 2023-01-05T21:21:39Z
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.193802] [info] Using profile api version 4
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.194547] [info] Found 3 turn restriction tags:
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.194557] [info]   motor_vehicle
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.194563] [info]   motorcar
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.194567] [info]   vehicle
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.194586] [info] Parse relations ...
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.783344] [info] Parse ways and nodes ...
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.787220] [info] Using profile api version 4
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.789438] [info] Using profile api version 4
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.791535] [info] Using profile api version 4
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.793467] [info] Using profile api version 4
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.795414] [info] Using profile api version 4
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.797358] [info] Using profile api version 4
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.799264] [info] Using profile api version 4
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.801137] [info] Using profile api version 4
[2023-01-06T09:11:58.803056] [info] Using profile api version 4
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type sol::error: lua: error: /Users/[omitted]/osrm-backend/profiles/lib/way_handlers.lua:480: attempt to compare string with number
Abort trap: 6
```

Note that I get the same error if I instead do:

```
osrm-extract norcal-latest.osm.pbf -p profiles/car.lua
```

If I try to instead do North America (`osrm-extract "north-america-latest.osm.pbf"`):

```
MacBook-Pro-2:osrm-backend $ osrm-extract "north-america-latest.osm.pbf"
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.703463] [info] Parsed 0 location-dependent features with 0 GeoJSON polygons
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.704033] [info] Using script profiles/car.lua
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.704056] [info] Input file: north-america-latest.osm.pbf
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.704065] [info] Profile: car.lua
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.704070] [info] Threads: 10
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.704394] [info] Parsing in progress..
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.704678] [info] input file generated by osmium/1.14.0
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.705304] [info] timestamp: 2023-01-05T21:21:39Z
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.712218] [info] Using profile api version 4
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.712997] [info] Found 3 turn restriction tags:
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.713007] [info]   motor_vehicle
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.713013] [info]   motorcar
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.713017] [info]   vehicle
[2023-01-27T21:18:48.713035] [info] Parse relations ...
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type osmium::pbf_error: PBF error: unexpected EOF
Abort trap: 6
```

How can I fix this?

Also note that the instructions in the first link, but ended up having to reinstall `lua` for it to work. If I uninstall lua, then when I run the `osrm-extract` code, it doesn't work at all and says:

```
dyld[36526]: Library not loaded: '/usr/local/opt/lua/lib/liblua.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/usr/local/bin/osrm-extract'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/lua/lib/liblua.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/liblua.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/liblua.dylib' (no such file)
Abort trap: 6
```

The funny thing is that if I try it with the Virgin Islands, it works.

Comment: Any reason this was tagged "r"? I don't see any R here so I've removed the tag.

Comment: That was my error - thanks for catching!